# IP Deny manager via php

Tags: php, ip, cpanel

I have written a class for anti brute force attacks, focusing on the attacker's IP. 
Is it possible to add an IP address to the cpanel -  IP Deny Manager through PHP code.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to access IP Deny Manager through PHP code but you can add that all IP's in your .htaccess file if you want to block your site access for that IP's